# Is it OK to spend 3 tons of fuel for the orbit transfer?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, poliastro

There are 2 coplanar orbits (same $i$,$\Omega$,$\omega$):

1. Apogee and perigee on 200km
2. Perigee on 700km, apogee on 8000 km

I used the `izzo.lambert` function from the `poliastro (python)` package to solve the problem.

I used the transfer time in the interval [30, 60*24*10] minutes and the true anomaly of the first maneuver in the interval [0,360]. The spacecraft mass is approximately 8 tons, İSP is about 330 s. The optimal transfer became:

1. 0.14 km/s impulse on 168 deg true anomaly of initial orbit
2. 1.32 km/s impulse on the perigee of destination orbit

Due to the last impulse, I spend almost 3 tons of fuel! Is this fine? Is it practically feasible to spend 3 tons in 1 impulse?

Is there a better way?

Comment: This feels like a homework problem, and one that is missing a bit of detail. To known the fuel, we would need to know the mass of the spacecraft, and the ISP of the fuel. I'm assuming you are going from orbit 1 to orbit 2, but there is no inclination. The dela-v numbers sound reasonable.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Added mass and İSP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem statement correctly, your maneuver is equivalent to a complete Hohmann transfer from 200km x 200km to 700km x 700km, followed immediately by the first burn (but not the circularization burn) of a second Hohmann from 700km to 8000km. The [online Hohmann calculator here](http://www.satsig.net/orbit-research/delta-v-geo-injection-calculator.htm) confirms your ∆v calculations.

The Tsiolkovsky equation can be rearranged to solve for final mass like so:

$$ \frac {m_0} { e ^ {\frac {\Delta v} {g_0 \cdot I_sp}} } = m_f $$
Assuming your 8 ton figure is the fully fueled mass of the spacecraft, the final mass after those burns is indeed just over 5 tons; nearly 3 tons of fuel is expended.

Whether that is feasible depends on the details of the spacecraft. The transfer ∆v calculations are assuming the ∆v is applied instantaneously, which is never the case in practice; somewhat more ∆v or fuel needs to be expended if it's spread over a significant amount of time. Another option is to do a series of short burns at the perigee of each orbit, raising the apogee a little bit at a time; the total ∆v applied will be the same.

Comment: Would it be better to raise the aphelion all the way first (ie boost to a 200 x 8000 elliptical orbit, Then boost at aphelion to raise the perihelion to 700?

Comment: @RusselBorogove  I don't think so. In units where $GM=1$ and distances are in $km$ the delta-V for going via 700x700 is 0.0341, while going via 8000x200 is 0.0289.  The point is to do the biggest useful burn at 200km.

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry.

Comment: Is it important to make burns at the perigee? Is it possible, that a different value for True Anomaly would be more optimal?

Comment: In this case, starting from a circular orbit, perigee burn is best. Going from one ellipse to a differently oriented ellipse, ask Lambert.

Comment: @Leeloo The advantage of doing your burns as low as possible is considerable.  If your burns are long it can even be worthwhile to split your burn up across multiple orbits.